# Java: reaching a file without specifying directory

Tags: java, file, directory, save

I have created a program that is creating and loading a Highscores.txt file. I want this program, when opened from a computer other than mine, to still be able to reach the txt file without having to save it in any specific directory. How could this be done?

Comment: What have you done so far? please post your code

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the other computer should do with that file and why it shouldn't save it in a specify directory?

Comment: If you're using that file like a leaderboard (i.e., all instances of your application, regardless of where it runs from, will use the same high scores), then you should just host it on the internet, and all instances get to it from the same URL.  If you're also wanting all instances to be able to modify it, then you don't want a file anyway, you want an API that can handle multiple updates at the same time, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Highscores.txt").getPath();
```

The unique condition for this is that the file have to be in the classpath, otherwise, this will be a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

- You need a location from where you need to access the file. The location can be local or remote. Since you do not want to read the file from local file system , this means that file has to be accessed from remote location. File can be hosted in a webserver(HTTP GET) , FTP location , remote directory on a different machine and scp from that location , or save as blob in the database and load from it.